# How do I identify an entity as a view in a T4 template for Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, t4, edmx

I'm using T4 templates to generate unit test code from EntityFramework 6.1 and need to avoid generating code for views.

If an entity is a view, its noted this way in the .EDMX file

```
<EntitySet Name="vwMyView" EntityType="Self.vwMyView" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="dbo">
```

I can get access to the EntitySet with this

```
foreach (EntityContainer container in ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityContainer>()) { 
    foreach (EntitySet set in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
    { 
        if (set.ElementType.Name == (class I'm generating)) {
          // get EntitySet stuff
        }
    } 
}
```

However, I can't for the life of me find the values of the 'store:Type' attribute. Its not in the MetadataProperties.

thanks in advance,

John

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The part of the edmx file you show is in the store model section, which is created while generating/updating the model from the database. The conceptual model part of the edmx, which is used for creating code, doesn't contain any information concerning the store type of the entities.

Comment: Thanks Gert, worst case scenario is that I could open the EDMX as an XML Document and find it with an XPath query but I hate coloring so far outside the lines because the next update could wipe that assumptions out. In the mean time I'm using naming conventions -- views begin with 'vw'. It seems like a reasonable thing to want to know, though, I wonder why they didn't provide a way to find out.

Comment: I think they thought that in this case people would never check the "views" mark in the "create model from database" dialog. The conceptual side of the model is supposed to be persistence ignorant, that should be the reason that this information is not available there.